# Need some clarification on a JavaScript lesson. (Constructor Functions)

Tags: javascript, function, class

I have the following code I need some clarification with. I want to understand it perfectly before I move on. I know the example might be silly and I am sure there is a lot of better ways to solve the problem but for the sake of this lesson the person used this example.

All I need is some clarification on how exactly the flow of the score function works and onwards. Where are the values coming from? How is it adding up each time the person gives the right answer?
I basically want to understand how this code generates the number to display to the console every time the user inputs a true value into the alert. I am sorry if I'm not coming through clearly, I just need to understand how the code works from `function score()` and onwards. I could not for the life of me figure it out. Where is sc getting its values from, and where does it pass it too and; and; and.
Is there anyone that's willing to give me a layout of how this code fits together. I would be eternally grateful.

```
(function() {
    function Question(question, answers, correct) {
        this.question = question;
        this.answers = answers;
        this.correct = correct;
    }

    Question.prototype.displayQuestion = function() {
        console.log(this.question);

        for (var i = 0; i < this.answers.length; i++) {
            console.log(i + ': ' + this.answers[i]);
        }
    }

    Question.prototype.checkAnswer = function(ans, callback) {
        var sc;

        if (ans === this.correct) {
            console.log('Correct answer!');
            sc = callback(true);
        } else {
            console.log('Wrong answer. Try again :)');
            sc = callback(false);
        }

        this.displayScore(sc);
    }

    Question.prototype.displayScore = function(score) {
        console.log('Your current score is: ' + score);
        console.log('------------------------------');
    }


    var q1 = new Question('Is JavaScript the coolest programming language in the world?',
                          ['Yes', 'No'],
                          0);

    var q2 = new Question('What is the name of this course\'s teacher?',
                          ['John', 'Micheal', 'Jonas'],
                          2);

    var q3 = new Question('What does best describe coding?',
                          ['Boring', 'Hard', 'Fun', 'Tediuos'],
                          2);

    var questions = [q1, q2, q3];

    function score() {
        var sc = 0;
        return function(correct) {
            if (correct) {
                sc++;
            }
            return sc;
        }
    }
    var keepScore = score();


    function nextQuestion() {

        var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length);
        questions[n].displayQuestion();

        var answer = prompt('Please select the correct answer.');

        if(answer !== 'exit') {
            questions[n].checkAnswer(parseInt(answer), keepScore);

            nextQuestion();
        }
    }

    nextQuestion();

})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sc` gets its value due to closure. When ever the nested function which is returned by `score()` and the `if` statement `if (correct)` is true then score gets incremented. Consider a general snippet below.

```js
function score(){
  let sc = 0;
  return function(correct){
    if(correct){
      
      sc++; //this is the same variable is upper scope.
      console.log(sc)
    }
    return sc;
  }
}

let temp = score();

temp(true);
temp(true);
```

So in the above snippet the outer function `score` is only called once and does two things:

- initialize a variable `sc` which is `0`
- return function in which `sc` will refer to the `sc` variable created in upper scope.

The use this is just to prevent making of global variable

Consider another simple snippet.

```js
let count = 0;

function counter(){
  count++;
  console.log(count)
}

counter();
counter();
counter();
```

In the above snippet the parent scope is global scope and child scope is scope of function. Now the variable `count` is present inside the the the `counter()`(even though its not declared inside `counter()`)  due to closure.

- Now in the first snippet the function `score()` is just like global scope(in second snippet),
- In first snippet the returned function is `return function(correct){...}` is just like the nested `counter()` function in second snippet.
- And `sc` variable is just like `count` variable.

> Could you maybe just explain the `prototype.checkAnswer` a little bit more

This method takes two arguments. `ans` and `callback`.

Consider the line in  function `nextQuestion()`

```
questions[n].checkAnswer(parseInt(answer), keepScore);
```

Now if you notice two parameters are passed to function. One is number of correct answer and other is a callback(a function which is passed to another function be be called later).

We are passing  `keepScore` which I explained above is the function returned by `score()` i.e `function(correct){...}`. Now this function is called inside the prototype method. This callback returns the value of `sc` which is declared in its parent function `score`. And then its displayed using `this.displayScore`

Now the thing you maybe confused with is the variable `sc` in the `prototype.checkAnswer`. That variable is just to prevent the double writing of `this.displayScore();`

The function can be written as:

```
Question.prototype.checkAnswer = function(ans, callback) {
    if (ans === this.correct) {
        console.log('Correct answer!');
        this.displayScore(callback(true));
    } else {
        console.log('Wrong answer. Try again :)');
        this.displayScore(callback(false));
    }        
}
```

**Even if we declare the other variable `sc` in `prototype.checkAnswer` it has not relation with the variable `sc` inside `score()`**. They are completely different variables because the variables declared with `var` have function scope.

Conisder the snippet:

```js
function score(){
  var sc = 0;
  return function(){
    sc++;
    console.log(`I am sc of score: ${sc}`);
    return sc;
  }
}

let temp = score();

function wrapper(callback){
  var sc = 0;
  console.log(`I am sc of wrapper: ${sc}`);
  callback();
}

wrapper(temp)
wrapper(temp)
wrapper(temp)
wrapper(temp)
```

Comment: You are amazing, thank you very much. I asked a very confusing question but you somehow still knew what I wanted... Have a wonderful day. Now I just need to fully understand closures xD

Comment: Could you maybe just explain the prototype.checkAnswer a little bit more?

Answer (score 1):

1. It's self-executing wrapper function. It automatically calls `nextQuestion()` to begin process
2. `var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length);` selects random question from your `questions` list
3. `displayQuestion()` shows information from second `new Question()` parameter as possible answers. Third parameter is correct answer.
4. User inputs it's answer in `prompt('Please select the correct answer.');` and if it's not `exit`, then comparing answer with correct value.
5. After showing answer code calls `keepScore(correct)` to add score to final result.
6. [GOTO #2] using `nextQuestion();`

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Can you maybe clarify how 1 is added up every time the answer is correct if sc = 0; Where are the values coming from? the sc = callback () has something to do with this?

Answer (score 1):

The slightly tricky bit for the uninitiated here is that the `score` function *returns a function* and makes use of a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

```js
function score() {
  var sc = 0;
  return function(correct) {
    if (correct) {
      sc++;
    }
    return sc;
  }
}
```

This line:

```js
var sc = 0;
```

creates a variable for holding the current score and then returns a function you can call to increment that variable. The variable can't be declared inside the function because it would get recreated every time the function was called:

```
// can't do this. sc gets recreated and reset on every call:
function score (correct) {
  var sc = 0;
  if (correct) {
    sc++
  }
  return sc;
}
```

But you also don't want the variable available to everyone, so you don't want to do this either:

```js
// don't want this either.
// score shouldn't be modifiable outside of our keepScore method.
let sc = 0;

function score (correct) {
  if (correct) {
    sc++;
  }
  return sc;
}

// this approach works, but now cheaters can set
// the score outside our scorekeeping function:
sc = 999999; // oh noes! hacks!
```

So what can we do? We can:

First: Create the variable within a function scope, where it's protected from outside shenanigans:

```js
function score () {
  var sc = 0; // unavailable outside this function
}
```

Second: Create another function *inside the first* that can modify the variable:

```js
function score () {
  var sc = 0; // unavailable outside this function

  // a new function that has access to the outer function's sc variable.
  function(correct) {
    if (correct) {
      sc++;
    }
    return sc;
  }
}
```

Finally, returning the inner function from `score()` gives outsiders a way to register correct answers without exposing the score variable itself:

```js
function score () {
  var sc = 0; // unavailable outside this function

  // return this function to the caller and voila!
  // they now have a self-contained scorekeeper function.
  return function(correct) {
    if (correct) {
      sc++;
    }
    return sc;
  }
}
```

So now when you do this:

```js
var keepScore = score();
```

`keepScore` is that inner function with its own internal `sc` variable.

If you had a multiplayer edition, you could get one for each player:

```js
// each gets their own instance of
// that inner function with its own
// independent sc variable.
const playerOneScore = score();
const playerTwoScore = score();

playerOneScore(true); // 1
playerOneScore(true); // 2

playerTwoScore(false); // 0
playerTwoScore(true); // 1
```

I think once you understand this bit, the rest will make a lot more sense.

Comment: Thank you Ray. I stepped into this thinking my post was most probably going to be deleted, as this was my first post ever on Stack. But I am pleasantly surprised by the amazing patient community on Stack. This will definitely be my goto place from now on. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I think most people around here are happy to help anyone who’s making a good-faith effort, truly trying to understand.

Comment: Just want to thank you again! I was going over your code and then something snapped. I couldn't believe I missed it. I overcomplicated the thing to such an extent I did not understand the correct in the return function... I feel so silly. I had two great examples and I still struggled, but I really understand now :D

Answer (score 1):

Here the score function is a Closure

The state of sc inside score is intialised when score is invoked.

`var keepScore = score();`

Now the keepScore contains the function which is returned by the closure 
that is

```
function (correct) {           
        if (correct) {
            sc++; // it has a "closure" over it
        }
        return sc;
    }
```

which accepts a boolean value. that is,
    keepScore(true) or keepScore(false)

Now this keepScore function is passed to check answer

`questions[n].checkAnswer(parseInt(answer), keepScore);`

In check anwer, if the answer is correct it will pass true to the keepScore

`callback(true) <=> keepScore(true)`

If you want to have more clarity on Closure you can go through this article

https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/up%20%26%20going/ch2.md#closure

Comment: I have some homework to do. I definitely need to have a much better understanding of closures. Thank you for the reference.